# Using static variables in Hooks React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i use static variable with `React Hooks`? 
I have a component and I want to pass it to hooks, but I have a problem because of `static`

Old Exemplo:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static myComponentInstance

  static show({...config}){
    this.myComponentInstance.start(config)
  }

  start({...config}){ // my code function here }
}
```

new Version

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const myComponentInstance = useRef(null)

  const start = ({...config}){ // my code function here }
}
```

I saw a bit of `useRef`, but I don't know if it's right to use it, and how I would make my show method `static`

doing this, I can call my component's method from another component (it already works with the class)

Ex:

```
import { Root, myComponent } from 'myComponent'

<Root>
  <a onclick="myComponent.show({...})">Show</a>
</Root>
```

Is it possible to use static `methods` with `react hooks`?

Comment: This doesn't look right at all. Why are you making the method static?

Comment: @randomusername because i want use in other component.

Comment: I don't think you're using the object oriented one correctly. You should be using context objects for this.

Comment: in initial code `static` method refers to `this` that makes no sense to me. what's a goal? could you describe business meaning or data flow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## You can't use `static` but properties and variables still exist

While @Clarity is right that you can't use static methods/properties with function based React components, a static method/property is, for your intents and purposes, the equivalent of a function/variable.

For one, you could simply attach the method and properties to your `MyComponent` like so:

```js
MyComponent.myComponentInstance = null
MyComponent.show = function() {}
// Using function keyword allows you to use the `this` keyword to reference MyComponent
```

### There are other options than OOP

The other option is to simply create variables/functions and export them. This will take advantage of the module system the same way you would by exporting your components.

```
export let myComponentInstance
export function show () {}
```

Then, to use them, you can import them:

```
import { myComponentInstance, show } from './example.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use React Hooks in class components at all, that means that `static` cannot be used with hooks either.

More info is in the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

Comment: I don't want use Hooks in class components, i want convert my class component to hooks

Comment: Well, in that case you won't be using a `static` keyword, since it can only be used in classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static